# What do softwares do when no one is watching them? (about Java unresponsive program)

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, thread-safety

I have been wondering this since my early school grades, now I think I have faced a real life scenario regarding this. There is an unexplainable delay in 2 consective log statements, here is the detail:

I am using slf4j with logback and here is what I got in my logs:

```
 INFO 2014-01-15 01:01:12,215 [Thread-38005034] 185 - REQ Rcvd:68506950
 INFO 2014-01-15 01:01:34,183 [Thread-38005035] 123 - [MGW150114010112fc1b][OC]923029563761->8803026062143 rDialogID: 68506950
```

These two lines should be printed with no time delay but it takes more than 20 secs for the second line to be printed.

Here is my code:

```
public void onRequest(final DPRequest arg0) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Request idp = new Request();
                idp.arg0 = arg0;
                Thread dpThread = new Thread(idp);
                dpThread.start();
                logger.info("REQ Rcvd:" + arg0.getId());
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

This is the request class

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        processdp();
    }

    public void processdp() {
            OCHandling ocsiHandler = new OCHandling(this.arg0);
            ocHandler.run();
    }
```

This is in the OCHandling class

```
public void run() {
        logger.info("[" + refId + "][OC]" + PNumber + "->" + CNumber + " rDialogID: " + arg0.getId());
}
```

onRequest function recieves almost 50 requests per second, this is the first time I have seen this much delay, and it only happened for less than a minute, where do you think could be the issue

1. Thread count: I have checked was normal
2. Logger not writting real time logs? Edit-> I found out this is not an issue
3. Any blocking request, this process wasnt given time in this slot?
4. Java does not pass parameters by reference so its not possible that the API which calls onRequest method is meddling with the parameter or what ever I dont know
5. This program is running on a VM which is on ESXI server

Comment: Could it be the garbage collector? Did this happen after some time running?

Comment: GC taking too much time to clean up does it do that any references?

Comment: Could you have too many threads running?

Comment: @Vijay: yes threads are running, but Im looking for any solid references or sources who have had known issues if high number of threads, the max thread count I have seen is about 500

Comment: It's possible it's an IO issue.  Without seeing all of your code it would be hard to say for sure.  Is your app IO intensive?  Other than the logging I mean...  I'd suggest you pass in your own (string) timestamp and see if you see the same behavior.  I'd add in more logging (before/after thread creation etc) to see if there is a specific line which is running slow...

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was a compaction problem

http://knucle.blogspot.com/2011/05/compaction-in-java-garbage-collection.html

never heard of that before, I could think of no reason why gc needs to stop all other threads while collecting unreferenced memory, but reading about this, it solves the mystery. Thanks for pointing to gc, which lead to this compaction thingy.